# On matrix tridiagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

Can any matrix $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be decomposed into a tridiagonal matrix, i.e.,

$$X = P^{-1}DP$$

where $P \in \mbox{SO}(n)$ and $D$ is [tridiagonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)?

Comment: If $P$ is orthogonal, why not use $P^\top$ instead of $P^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3):

B. Sturmfels has proved the following result in the complex case:

> For every $n\ge6$, there exists a complex $n\times n$ matrix that is not unitarily similar to a tridiagonal matrix.

A proof, due to J.L. Noakes, was given in W.E. Longstaff, [On Tridiagonalization of Matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(88)90206-6), *Linear and Its Applications*, 109:153-163, 1988. Apparently, the dimension argument employed in this proof can be extended to the real case (and the answer then is negative when $n\ge5$).